# CodeIgniter: LEFT JOIN in $this->db->query returns a database error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I need to exclude second query (data from a second table) similar to MINUS. But since MySQL doesn't support MINUS, I decided to go with LEFT JOIN. However it gives me a database error.

[image]

**Model**

```
function searchRooms($room_type, $start_date, $end_date) {
// Line 6 is the below one:
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT     room_number
        FROM        rooms
        WHERE       room_type = '$room_type'
        ORDER BY    room_number ASC

        LEFT JOIN

        SELECT      room_number
        FROM        new_reservation
        WHERE       start_date >= '$start_date'
        AND         end_date <= '$end_date'
        ORDER BY    room_number ASC
        ");
    return $query->result();

}
```

**Controller**

```
function search() {
        $room_type = $this->input->post('room_type');
        $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
        $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
        $this->reservations_model->searchRooms($room_type, $start_date, $end_date);

        $this->index();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to exclude result from second query then

```
  SELECT room_number
    FROM rooms
   WHERE room_type = '$room_type'
     AND room_number not in (SELECT room_number
                          FROM new_reservation
                         WHERE start_date >= '$start_date'
                           AND end_date <= '$end_date')
ORDER BY room_number ASC
```

Using join instead of subquery

```
  SELECT a.room_number
    FROM rooms a left outer join (SELECT room_number
                          FROM new_reservation
                         WHERE start_date >= '$start_date'
                           AND end_date <= '$end_date') b
      ON a.room_number = b.room_number
   WHERE a.room_type = '$room_type'
     AND b.room_number is null
ORDER BY a.room_number ASC
```

Again if you don't want to use inline view

```
  SELECT a.room_number
    FROM rooms a left outer join new_reservation b
      ON a.room_number = b.room_number
   WHERE a.room_type = '$room_type'
     AND b.start_date >= '$start_date'
     AND b.end_date <= '$end_date'
     AND b.room_number is null
ORDER BY a.room_number ASC
```

Comment: subqueries inside where clauses are very, very slow.

Comment: it depends on the cardinality, index, execution plan, etc

Comment: yes. But still, 99% of the time It's better to figure how to use a join instead of a subquery inside a where.

Comment: I doubt about your statistic. But as your wish, I am re-writing query using join

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) is wrong, it should be something in the form of:

```
SELECT     room_number
FROM        rooms
LEFT JOIN .... ON ...
WHERE  ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Or are you looking for a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) instead of a `LEFT JOIN`?

Although in your case you could probably just invert the conditions of the second query and use that as a `WHERE` condition in the first query (if I understand you correctly...).

Comment: As user 'chetan' pointed out, I used LEFT OUTER JOIN and tested with few values as well. So far the results are accurate. Currently, testing further.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you JOIN tables, not SELECT statements.  LEFT JOIN is used when the JOINed table may not have a matching row in it.

You want to JOIN and select only the rows you want.

Try this:

```
SELECT rooms.room_number
FROM rooms
JOIN new_reservation ON rooms.room_number = new_reservation.room_number
WHERE rooms.room_type = '$room_type'
AND NOT (start_date >= '$start_date' AND end_date <= '$end_date')
ORDER BY room_number ASC
```

Comment: As user 'chetan' pointed out, I used LEFT OUTER JOIN and tested with few values as well. So far the results are accurate. Currently, testing further.

Answer (score 0):

In the codeigniter You can use like this

```
$this->db->query("select tb.required_field,tb.another_require_field from table_name as tb
    left join another_table_name as atb on atb.common_column = tb.common_column 
      where tb.conditional_colun= condition");
```

This is the syntax that i uses in my application